# Distributing iOS App within and outside the organisation

Tags: ios, app-distribution

We are developing an iOS application which is supposed to be distributed within our organization. I know Apple Enterprise program is the best choice for this. But, in future, we are planning to distribute the App outside of the organization too. Which is the best way to go ahead, Apple Enterprise program or Custom B2B? Also, is there any legal issues in distributing the Custom B2B app within our organization?

Comment: Enterprize is the only package of the three that will allow you to dist without loading UUIDs beforehand and you can go public as well with it.

Comment: It depends on how you want to distribute the app to those outside your organisation. Enterprise apps can only be distributed to those within your organisation, preferably via an MDM but you can use a normal https web server. B2B apps also require an MDM for distribution but you can make it available to other organisations for them to load onto their MDM. If you distribute via the App Store then anyone can download it and you can also distribute internally via an MDM